# How to redirect toa particular section of a different html page which has owl carouselin it

Tags: php, html, css, redirect, owl-carousel

I want to redirect the user to a particular section of an html page.

```js
// javascript for owl
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.owl-two').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
 autoplay:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:2
        },
        1000:{
            items:3
        }
    }
});
});
```

```html
<!-- nav-->
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li><a href="salon_services.php#hair">Hair</a></li>
<li><a  href="salon_services.php#nail">Nail</a></li>
   <li><a  href="salon_services.php#wax">Wax</a></li>
</ul>
                  
                  <!-- owl carousel in salon services page-->
                  <div id="nail" class="row" >
  <br>
  <br>
  <h3 class="text-center">Our Nail Services</h3>
  <br>
  <!-- nail carousal-->
  <div class="owl-two owl-carousel owl-theme">
   <div class="item"><img src="images/n1.jpg" alt="Image" class=" img-thumbnail">
   <h4 class="text-center">Manicure</h4>
   </div>   
   <div class="item"><img src="images/n2.jpg" alt="Image" class=" img-thumbnail">
   <h4 class="text-center">Pedicure</h4>
   </div>   
   <div class="item"><img src="images/n3.jpg" alt="Image" class=" img-thumbnail">
   <h4 class="text-center">Nail Painting and Design</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="item"><img src="images/n4.jpg" alt="Image" class=" img-thumbnail">
   <h4 class="text-center">Nail Extensions</h4>
   </div>
   
  </div>
```

I want to redirect the user directly from `nav` dropdown to another page's `div` containing that content. The page to which I want to redirect has 3 owl carousels.

I have already tried the html id redirect. `<a href="#id">`, but it does not works completely. The page redirects briefly to the section but scrolls automatically to the top of the page.

I am using the owl carousel and think that owl javascript is the responsible factor for this as I have tested it with removing owl and it works, also the id redirect works fine when done from the same page (i.e.services page ).
I have 3 carousels 1.hair 2.nail 3.wax
Kindly help I want to keep owl and the section redirect function. Thanks.

Comment: You need to add a minimal reproducible example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score -1):

```css
.sec {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#one">One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Four">Four</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="one" class="sec">
    <h1>One</h1>
</div>


<div id="two" class="sec">
    <h1>Two</h1>
</div>



<div id="three" class="sec">
    <h1>Three</h1>
</div>


<div id="four" class="sec">
    <h1>Four</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: the redirect to different sections using <a href="#id"> is working when i remove the owl carousel but not working with the owl carousel. i have a services page with 3 different service types and want the user to direct from any page to that specific service section. Using the <a href="#id"> redirects it to the specific section for a split second abd then scrolls to the top of the page. I am using 3 owl carousels. Thanks

Comment: <li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href=""> Services <span class="fa fa-caret-down"><span> </a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="salon_services.php#hair">Hair</a></li>
<li><a  href="salon_services.php#nail">Nail</a></li>
<li><a  href="salon_services.php#wax">Wax</a></li>         </ul></li>  This is the code for redirecting to section.

Comment: This is the code for a single owl carousel -  javascript $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.owl-one').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
 autoplay:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:2
        },
        1000:{
            items:3
        }
    }
});
});

Comment: this is the carousel code -  <div id="hair" class="row"> <div class="owl-one owl-carousel owl-theme">
<div class="item"><img src="images/h1.jpg" alt="Image" class=" img-thumbnail"></div>
<div class="item"><img src="images/h2.jpg" alt="Image" class=" img-thumbnail"></div>
<div class="item"><img src="images/h3.jpg" alt="Image" class=" img-thumbnail"></div>
<div class="item"><img src="images/h4.png" alt="Image" class=" img-thumbnail"></div>
 </div></div>